# jquery Populate dropdown with json data

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu

Good day,

I have looked online and read the posts regarding dropdowns using json and jquery.  However I can't seem to get my syntax correct.  When the page loads, I want the towns dropdown to contain all the towns.  Once a user picks a community, then only the communities for that town should show.

Any help is appreciated.  Please view my code here http://jsfiddle.net/latoyale/XgxCP/1/

Comment: You want to bind to the `change` event, not the `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

I made a working fork: http://jsfiddle.net/ccync/

For posterity, JavaScript code is below:

```
// JSON data start

var data = [
     [
                {optionValue: 0,url: 'Choose Town',community: 'Choose Town'},
                {optionValue: 1,url: '/dutchess/amenia',community: 'Amenia'},
                {optionValue: 2,url: '/dutchess/arlington',community: 'Arlington'},
                {optionValue: 3,url: '/dutchess/barrytown',community: 'Barrytown'}
     ],


            [   {optionValue: 0,url: 'Choose Town',community: 'Choose Town'},
                {optionValue: 32,url: '/orange/Campbell-hall',community: 'Campbell Hall'},
                {optionValue: 33,url: '/orange/central-valley',community: 'Central Valley'},
                {optionValue: 34,url: '/orange/chester',community: 'Chester'},
   ]

           ];

// JSON data end


$(function() {

    $('#page-changer')[0].reset(); // resets form onload

    var $county = $('#county');
    var $township = $('#township');  
    function updateTownshipOptions(){
        var selected = $county.val();
        if (selected) {
            options = [];
            var selected_data = data[$county.val()-1];
            for (var i=0; i<selected_data.length; i++) {
                options.push('<option value="'+selected_data[i].optionValue+'">'+selected_data[i].community+'</option>');
            }
            $township.html(options.join(''));
        }
    }    
    updateTownshipOptions();
    $county.change(updateTownshipOptions);

});
```

Comment: Thank you this is definitely more sophisticated then my original code.  Howeverthe towns drop down doesn't populate with all the towns on load.  I need all the "communities" to show if a user clicks the towns drop down first.  Once the county drop down is selected, the the list should only show the towns for that county.

Comment: The problem with that is the way you've set up your `data`. It's not practical to loop through each of the sets of options, filter out the "Choose a Town" option and roll them all into one list. The way this is typically done, is that your original form includes all possible options. Then, when a county is chosen, it fires off an AJAX request to fetch the options just for that chosen selection.

Comment: I can revamp my data to accommodate this functionality. Once I do, I want to know what the syntax is to retrieve the community data.

Comment: $(township).empty(); gives me an empty array...can I do something like $(township).inArray(community) or .data(community) to give me the info I need?

Comment: @latoyale. I updated the jsfiddle provided by Chris so that all the towns are loaded on page load. I just wrote an 'else' code. Here is the link to it http://jsfiddle.net/ccync/3/